# concurrency modeling in PHP for looping through data within a foreach function

Tags: php, drop-down-menu, concurrency, foreach, while-loop

I have a table for property listings. columns include: id, title, address, sale_price, lease_price, img_listing blah blah

I'm using a  server side (must be server side!) script to paginate allow user to browse through each listing (1 at a time). My script sets the LIMIT and the OFFSET, and then PDO selects and displays the data like so:

```
   $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM listings Order by id DESC LIMIT :limit OFFSET :offset ');
   $stmt->bindParam(':limit', $limit, PDO::PARAM_INT);
   $stmt->bindParam(':offset', $offset, PDO::PARAM_INT);
   $stmt->execute();
if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
    $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $iterator = new IteratorIterator($stmt);
    foreach ($iterator as $row) {
    echo $row['title'] $row['address'] $row['sale_price'] $row['img_listing'];
    }
```

this works fine. Now I need to add a drop-down list that shows ALL of the values in the column 'title', that way if the user knows the title he doesn't need to click through every property. I'm thinking a while loop would be appropriate but I don't know, I'm already running foreach, so I would need to definae new variables such as idALL and titleALL:

```
              echo
                while(????????)
        {
          '<select><option value="' . $row['idALL'] . '">' . $row['titleALL'] . '</option></select>';
        }
```

How can a drop down list like this be added to the same page when I'm doing this prev/next type of pagination? An acceptable answer to this questions would include mentioning a better overall method to for what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Run a seperate query to generate the list of titles for your dropdown?

Comment: @Darren Thank you Darren, I considered that, But where would i run it. Remember I need to use the same variable 'id' and 'title' and I can't see how to avoid overlapping them?

Comment: Why did you mention concurrency in the title? Does your _listings_ table change very often (as in multiple updates per second)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm having a little bit of trouble understanding the question, are you just trying to generate a dropdown list of each property? If so, it looks like you're almost there.

You've already got a `foreach` going, just make a variable outside the loop to hold all the `option` elements, then output it inside the select.

Example:

```
// empty options string
$options = '';

foreach ($iterator as $row) {
    echo $row['title'] $row['address'] $row['sale_price'] $row['img_listing'];

    // add each option to the end of the string
    $options .= '<option value="' . $row['id'] . '">' . $row['title'] . '</option>';
}

// Finally output select element
echo '<select>'.$options.'</select>';
```

(the code above is untested, but should give you a rough idea)

Comment: The query the OP posted above itterates one property at a time. So it only returns one row at a time. I think he wants a dropdown with "all" the properties, so that people can choose a property to view instead of having to scroll through them one by one.